# Comparing an element to any in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, any

I am trying to build a function which would help me to fetch adjacent regions by finding the ones sharing the same vertices. A Region object has a method *getVertices* which will return a list of tuples:
[(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)].
It also has a property and method for setting an Id to be further reused (*setId*/*getId* below). 
I`m trying to iterate through a list of regions (variable called regions), assign Ids first and then iterate again - for each vertice in each region, loop through the rest of regions to see if any of them holds this vertice in their vertices set. However, below is failing:

```
    def findAdjacent(regions):
i = 0
for region in regions:
    region.setId(i)
    i += 1
for region in regions:
    for vertice in region.getVertices():
        for regionN in regions:
            if any(vertice == v for v in regionN.getVertices()):
                region.addAdjacent(regionN.getId)

if any(vertice == v for v in regionn.getVertices()):
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

I was under impression that this could be failing because it somehows considers a tuple being a list instead but apparently this is not the case as two tuple objects should be compared just fine. Would you mind pointing me to the flaw in my logic here?

Comment: Um, this error message implies you are working wtih `numpy.ndarray` objects (or a `pandas` object). Note `tuple` or `list` Anyway, you'll need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Indeed, found out vertices initialized as ndarray instead of being tuples. I`ll proceed from there, thank you!